# Random Error From Node.Js and Lua HTTP Get?

Tags: node.js, lua, pipedream

So I'm trying to recieve data like the clients IP from a pipedream workflow using lua(HTTPGET). And so I have a custom body response in Node.JS with no errors. However, when I print the body response in Lua I get this unusual error. It prints the ip but then says A malformed number is near the clients ip.:

My Node.JS code for pipedream:

```
await $respond({
  status: 200,
  immediate: true,
  body: `${steps.trigger.event.client_ip}`
})
```

There are no errors, its fine but heres my Lua code to get the response:

```
function GetServProtocal()
    print(loadstring(game:HttpGet('https://enznhjjype22xb2.m.pipedream.net')))()
end

GetServProtocal()
```

Also, no errors but the output is weird:

```
-- I'm using 1.1.1.1 example ip for code so I don't expose my real one.

[string "1.1.1.1"]:1: malformed number near "1.1.1.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `loadstring` from your code. The `loadstring` function expects some Lua code, which it will turn into an executable function and the string that is being returned by `HttpGet` is not a valid Lua code, hence the error you get.